# How to solve an http 500 error status when im testing my code using jest on node js

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, prisma, http-status-code-500

This is my unit testing file and when i test this code, it gives me 500 http error sayin that prisma: error and Argument `id`: Invalid value provided. Expected IntFilter or Int, provided Boolean.

```
describe("POST /api/contacts/:contactId/addresses", function () {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await createTestUser();
    await createTestContact();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await removeAllTestAddresses();
    await removeAllTestContact();
    await removeTestUser();
  });

  it("should create new address", async () => {
    const testContact = await getTestContactId();

    const result = await supertest(web)
      .post("/api/contacts/" + testContact.id + "/addresses")
      .set("Authorization", "test")
      .send({
        street: "jalan test",
        city: "kota test",
        province: "provinsi test",
        country: "dorra",
        postal_code: "234234",
      });

    logger.info(result.body);

    expect(result.status).toBe(200);
    expect(result.body.data.id).toBeDefined();
    expect(result.body.data.street).toBe("jalan test");
    expect(result.body.data.city).toBe("kota test");
    expect(result.body.data.province).toBe("provinsi test");
    expect(result.body.data.country).toBe("dorra");
    expect(result.body.data.postal_code).toBe("234234");
  });
});
```

And This is my validation code, based on jest this is where the error come from

```
const create = async (user, contactId, request) => {
  contactId = validate(getContactValidation, contactId);

  const totalContactInDatabase = await prismaClient.contact.count({
    where: {
      username: user.username,
      id: contactId,
    },
  });

  if (totalContactInDatabase !== 1) {
    throw new ResponseError(404, "Contact is not found");
  }

  const address = validate(createAddressValidation, request, { abortEarly: false });
  address.contact_id = contactId;

  return prismaClient.address.create({
    data: address,
    select: {
      id: true,
      street: true,
      city: true,
      province: true,
      country: true,
      postal_code: true,
    },
  });
};

export default {
  create,
};
```